# Python: Split a list into two. One list of floats, one list of strings

Tags: python

I have a list that contains floats and strings ex: [1.456, 'upn', 7.965, 'bvb']  How can I separate these into two lists that would read
[1.456, 7.95] and ['upn' , 'bvb']

Answer (score 3):

```
float_list = []
string_list = []
for item in first_list:
    if isinstance(item, float):
        float_list.append(item)
    elif isinstance(item, str):
        string_list.append(item)
```

Comment: Careful with ```isinstance(item, str)```: This will work in Python 3.x but not Python 2.x

Answer (score 3):

For Python 2.x:

```
lst = [1.456, 'upn', 7.965, 'bvb']
[i for i in lst if isinstance(i, basestring)]
[i for i in lst if isinstance(i, float)]
```

For Python 3.x:

```
lst = [1.456, 'upn', 7.965, 'bvb']
[i for i in lst if isinstance(i, str)]
[i for i in lst if isinstance(i, float)]
```

Output:

```
['upn', 'bvb']
[1.456, 7.965]
```

Comment: To this and prev cmnt ....   Apologies, I'm new to Python, but I do wonder at the rationale for an 'enhancement' going from 2.x to 3.x that would seem to break code.   Backwards compatability is not Pythonesque?

Comment: Yes, see here: http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit

Answer (score 2):

One way would be using slicing `some_list[start:end:step]`:

```
b = a[::2]
c = a[1::2]

print b
print c
```

**Output:**

```
[1.456, 7.965]
['upn', 'bvb']
```

**Note:** This approach will only work if the list follows the pattern `[float, str, float, str...]`

Comment: This doesn't separate floats and strings.

Comment: Just to let the OP know this will only work if the list was in the format `[float, str, float, str]` as it doesn't check for type.

Comment: I will clarify that. Edited.

Comment: Arguably, this is the much better solution - generally checking types explicitly should be avoided in Python - if you know the list will be in that format (as implied in the original post), working by position is probably the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
filter(lambda x:type(x) == str,[1.456, 'upn', 7.965, 'bvb'])
filter(lambda x:type(x) == float,[1.456, 'upn', 7.965, 'bvb'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> mixed_list = [1.456, 'upn', 7.965, 'bvb']
>>> temp_list = sorted(mixed_list)
>>> output_tuple = next( (temp_list[:temp_list.index(i):1],temp_list[temp_list.index(i):]) for i in temp_list if type(i) == str)
>>> output_tuple[0]
[1.456, 7.965]
>>> output_tuple[1]
['bvb', 'upn']

>>> sorted(mixed_list)
[1.456, 7.965, 'bvb', 'upn']
```

Here first I have sorted the list which arranges them in float and string order.
Then I have used next as iterator to check for first occurrence of 'string' and as soon as I get string the iterator will stop and give us the result.
It seems little complicated but it is faster then other methods where you have to iterate over whole list.
It can be very efficient if you have a big input list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than strings and float, you can try sorting the elements in a list by their `type(x)`, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> lst = [1.456, 'upn', 7.965, 'bvb']
>>> ddict = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in lst:
...     ddict[type(i)].append(i)
... 
>>> for i in ddict:
...     print i, ddict[i]
... 
<type 'float'> [1.456, 7.965]
<type 'str'> ['upn', 'bvb']
```